# Application for general conversion of a project on Visual C++ to Borland C++ Builder

Tags: visual-c++, c++builder, project-conversion

A lot of people would say "why u not use Visual Studio", but I would like to convert some of my Visual C++ projects to Borland C++ Builder projects because I'm more familiar with BCB...

Do someone know a tool on Borland C++ Builder or Visual Studio, or a 3rd party software or add-on to do it?

I have some projects on VS2008, VS2010 and VS6.

I have some machines with BCB6 and Borland Developer Studio 2006...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tool simply does not exist. C++ Builder is based on RTL and VCL libraries, in the other side, Visual C++ uses MFC and other libraries.
The architecture is completely different, they are not compatible and you cannot migrate the code. You need to rewrite most of code again from zero, specially code focused to user interface.

For non visual code, I develop in both platforms, VC and C++ Builder. When I need to share the source, I use the minimum common denominator that I have found in [C++ Standard Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++_Standard_Library) and [Boost](http://www.boost.org/). In this case, a conversion tool is not necessary since the source is fully compatible between the two platforms.